# Join tables to get readings before and after session

Tags: sql, presto

I have 2 tables A, B.

A - contains periodic readings:

| timestamp | reading |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |

B - contains session information:

| start | end | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 | 7 |

I want to join them together so that I can get the readings right before and after the session happens:

| start | end | before_reading_timestamp | after_reading_timestamp | value | before_reading | after_reading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 | 3 | 7 | 5 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 7 | 5 | 7 | 6 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 7 | 5 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 4 |

Explanation:
Take for example the first session `[start=1, end=2]`.
The reading closest and before or equal to `start=1` is `[timestamp=1, reading=1]`, and the reading closest and after or equal to `end=2` is `[timestamp=3, reading=2]`.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT
a.start,
a.end,
before.timestamp,
after.timestamp,
a.value,
before.reading,
after.reading
FROM B b
JOIN A before ON b.start >= before.timestamp
JOIN A after ON b.end <= after.timestamp
```

This generates a lot of extra rows due to the range joins. How can I filter out the rows that do not have timestamps right before and after the session?

Comment: Can you explain the columns before_reading and after_reading in your expected output?

Comment: @forpas Each session has a start and end timestamp. I want to know what the reading was before and after the session.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lead()` to get a time frame for the readings.  Then `join`:

```
with r as (
      select a.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from a
     )
    select b.*, rs.value as before_value, re.value as end_value
    from b left join
         r rs
         on b.start >= rs.timestamp and
            (b.start < rs.next_timestamp or rs.next_timestamp is null) left join
        r re
         on b.end >= re.timestamp and
            (b.start < re.next_timestamp or re.next_timestamp is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and use window functions `MAX()`, `MIN()` and `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.start, b.end, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.timestamp <= b.start THEN a.timestamp END) OVER (PARTITION BY b.start, b.end) before_reading_timestamp,
       MIN(CASE WHEN a.timestamp >= b.end THEN a.timestamp END) OVER (PARTITION BY b.start, b.end) after_reading_timestamp,
       b.value,
       FIRST_VALUE(a.reading) OVER (PARTITION BY b.start, b.end ORDER BY a.timestamp <= b.start DESC, a.timestamp DESC) before_reading,
       FIRST_VALUE(a.reading) OVER (PARTITION BY b.start, b.end ORDER BY a.timestamp >= b.end DESC, a.timestamp) after_reading
FROM b LEFT JOIN a
ON a.timestamp <= b.start OR a.timestamp >= b.end;
```

Or, for this sample data where there are ascending readings:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.start, b.end, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.timestamp <= b.start THEN a.timestamp END) OVER (PARTITION BY b.start, b.end) before_reading_timestamp,
       MIN(CASE WHEN a.timestamp >= b.end THEN a.timestamp END) OVER (PARTITION BY b.start, b.end) after_reading_timestamp,
       b.value,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.timestamp <= b.start THEN a.reading END) OVER (PARTITION BY b.start, b.end) before_reading,
       MIN(CASE WHEN a.timestamp >= b.end THEN a.reading END) OVER (PARTITION BY b.start, b.end) after_reading
FROM b LEFT JOIN a
ON a.timestamp <= b.start OR a.timestamp >= b.end;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4bf069012fef361543563de1d4d842f6).